# I'm not a Zebra

Tags: riddle

> I'm usually black and white
>   I'm not a Zebra, but perhaps a Panda is named after part of me
>   I'm always perfectly in harmony
>   Because that is what I say
>   I consist of two parts, and two times three lines is what I start with
>   I might be on your arm or leg, hand or foot, but at the same time I'm all around the universe
>   I consist of two times 2, a 6 and the final number of a different base
>   I'm like your left heart and right liver, one in down and the other up out
>   The easy one to find is made by G. Maxwell

What am I? (The answer is probably pretty easy, but please give why for each of the lines.)

---

*Tim Couwelier* has the correct answer, but who knows the last line:

> I consist of two times 2, a 6 and the final number of a different base

Hint(s):

> I consist of two times 2, a 6 and the final **letter** of a different base
>  **, and in *addition* I usually also consists of you**
>
>  It doesn't have anything to do with the shape of the Yin Yang symbol

Comment: You're a zebra, aren't you? Tricky disguising zebras...

Comment: @IanMacDonald Yep, definitely a zebra.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are:

> The Yin Yang symbol

I'm usually black and white

> It's typically displayed in black and white

I'm not a Zebra, but perhaps a Panda is named after part of me

> The [Yang Yang panda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yang_Yang_%28Atlanta_giant_panda%29)

I'm always perfectly in harmony
Because that is what I say

> The symbol symbolizes harmony

I consist of two parts, and two times three lines is what I start with

> Refers to the starting letters Y (which consist of three lines) - credit to **Aleeeeee**

I might be on your arm or leg, hand or foot, but at the same time I'm all around the universe

> Reference to tattoo's - it's a common tattoo theme / they are also linked with 'Moon' and 'Sun' (for the universe part)

I consist of two times 2, a 6 and the final number of a different base

> Unicode U+262F is the yin yang symbol: ☯

I'm like your left heart and right liver, one in down and the other up out

> It appears (source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yin_and_yang)) that 'left heart' is 'yang' and 'right lever' is 'yin'.

The easy one to find is made by G. Maxwell

> [SVG image on wikimedia commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Yin_yang.svg)

Comment: If anyone has a more sensible idea on the clue 'I consist of two times 2..' do let me know :)

Comment: +1 Most correct, not all though. "I consist of two lines..."; "I consist of two times 2..." and "I'm like your left heart..." are incorrect. The one with Panda is incorrect as well, but your answer is a lot better. ;) I didn't even knew a Yang Yang Panda existed tbh, I was merely referencing to Yin and Yang both being pretty popular names in China and Pandas are Chinese. (PS: As for the "I'm like your left heart..." it isn't completely wrong, but the answer I was looking for comes from a different _source_. In this case, the last one (with "G. Maxwell") can be used as hint.)

Comment: *I consist of two parts, and two times three lines is what I start with* refers to the letter **Y**, composed by 3 lines at the beginning of both the words

Comment: @Aleeeeee Correct, two more to go. :)

Comment: Tweaked the organ one, and the two times three lines. Should be just the 'two times 2...' one remaining.

Comment: @TimCouwelier Indeed. Btw, with the "left heart" <-> "right liver" one you are indeed correct, but the wikipedia list also contains the "in down" <-> "up out". But indeed, just the "`I consist of two times 2, a 6 and the final number of a different base`" remaining.

Comment: `I consist of two times 2, a 6 and the final number of a different base` sounds to me like two shapes of 2 colors (the 2 main pieces and the 2 circles) -- The half with the point facing upward resembles a 6, and its counterpart resembles a 9 which is the final *number* of any base above decimal, as following digits are represented by letters.  \* **Edit**: This applies to the flipped version of the one found on Wikimedia.

Comment: ^ Ehhh. I know part of my explanation may be weak, but pretty sure the 2x2 part fits.

Comment: @feelinferrety Original, but no. As a hint: It doesn't have anything to do with the shape of the Yin Yang symbol, and the line could also be changed to "I consist of two times 2, a 6 and the final **letter** of a different base" instead with the same answer.

Comment: Well, it appears ffao found the last missing link. No way I'd have come up with that myself (nor realise it has an unicode :s)